# Hamcrest equal collections

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, assert, hamcrest

Is there a matcher in Hamcrest to compare collections for equality?
There is `contains` and `containsInAnyOrder` but I need `equals` not bound to concrete collection type.
E.g. I cannot compare Arrays.asList and Map.values with Hamcrest `equals`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/2509293/21499

Comment: `Arrays.asList().equals(new HashMap<>().values()) == false` `List`s and `Set`s are never equal to each other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I cannot compare Arrays.asList and
>   Map.values with Hamcrest equals.

This is because of hamcrest's over-zealous type signatures. You *can* do this equality comparison, but you need to cast the `List` object to `Collection` before it'll compile.

I often have to do casting with Hamcrest, which feels wrong, but it's the only way to get it to compile sometimes.

Answer (score 4):

Casting to a Collection may work, but it makes some assumptions about the underlying Collection implementations (e.g., order?).  A more general approach would be to write your own matcher.

Here's a nearly complete matcher implementation that does what you want (you'll need to fill in the imports and describeTo method).  Note that this implementation requires all elements of two collections to be equal, but not necessarily in the same order.

```
public class IsCollectionOf<T> extends TypeSafeMatcher<Collection<T>> {
    private final Collection<T> expected;
    public IsCollectionOf(Collection<T> expected) {
        this.expected = expected;
    }
    public boolean matchesSafely(Collection<T> given) {
        List<T> tmp = new ArrayList<T>(expected);
        for (T t : given) {
            if (!tmp.remove(t)) {
                return false;
            }
        return tmp.isEmpty();
    }
    // describeTo here
    public static <T> Matcher<Collection<T>> ofItems(T... items) {
        return new IsCollectionOf<T>(Arrays.asList(items));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have trouble with the equals method of the collections implementation, you might also first copy the collections:

```
assertThat( new ArrayList<Whatever>(actual), equalTo( new ArrayList<Whatever>(expected) );
```

Also the following might work:

```
assertThat(actual, both(everyItem(isIn(expected))).and(containsInAnyOrder(expected)));
```