# Map equality using Hamcrest

Tags: java, collections, hamcrest

I'd like to use hamcrest to assert that two maps are equal, i.e. they have the same set of keys pointing to the same values.

My current best guess is:

```
assertThat( affA.entrySet(), hasItems( affB.entrySet() );
```

which gives:

> The method `assertThat(T, Matcher<T>)` in the type `Assert` is not applicable for the arguments (`Set<Map.Entry<Householdtypes,Double>>, Matcher<Iterable<Set<Map.Entry<Householdtypes,Double>>>>`)

I've also looked into variations of `containsAll`, and some others provided by the hamcrest packages. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Or do I have to write a custom matcher?

Comment: I have also tried `containsAll` et al. some time ago and it didn't seem to work - apparently hamcrest is a bit unreliable yet :-(

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use the `.equals()` of the Map implementation?

Comment: Ah - I hadn't realised that collections do proper .equals() comparisons. Has it always been like that? That makes life much easier! Thank you!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The shortest way I've come up with is two statements:

```
assertThat( affA.entrySet(), everyItem(isIn(affB.entrySet())));
assertThat( affB.entrySet(), everyItem(isIn(affA.entrySet())));
```

But you can probably also do:

```
assertThat(affA.entrySet(), equalTo(affB.entrySet()));
```

depending on the implementations of the maps, and sacrificing the clarity of the difference report: that would just tell you that there is a difference, while the statement above would also tell you which one.

UPDATE: actually there is one statement that works independently of the collection types:

```
assertThat(affA.entrySet(), both(everyItem(isIn(affB.entrySet()))).and(containsInAnyOrder(affB.entrySet())));
```

Comment: @Taras: the reporting is less helpful with `.equals()`

Comment: I had to convert the second access to affB into an array: `.and(containsInAnyOrder(affB.entrySet().toArray())`

Comment: incorporating both the missing `()` for `entrySet` and the necessary `toArray()` this ends up being: `assertThat(affA.entrySet(), both(everyItem(isIn(affB.entrySet()))).and(containsInAnyOrder(affB.entrySet().toArray())))`

Answer (score 41):

Sometimes `Map.equals()` is enough. But sometimes you don't know the types of `Map`s is returned by code under tests, so you don't know if `.equals()` will properly compare that map of unknown type returned by code with map constructed by you. Or you don't want to bind your code with such tests.

Additionally, constructing a map separately to compare the result with it is IMHO not very elegant:

```
Map<MyKey, MyValue> actual = methodUnderTest();

Map<MyKey, MyValue> expected = new HashMap<MyKey, MyValue>();
expected.put(new MyKey(1), new MyValue(10));
expected.put(new MyKey(2), new MyValue(20));
expected.put(new MyKey(3), new MyValue(30));
assertThat(actual, equalTo(expected));
```

I prefer using machers:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasEntry;

Map<MyKey, MyValue> actual = methodUnderTest();
assertThat(actual, allOf(
                      hasSize(3), // make sure there are no extra key/value pairs in map
                      hasEntry(new MyKey(1), new MyValue(10)),
                      hasEntry(new MyKey(2), new MyValue(20)),
                      hasEntry(new MyKey(3), new MyValue(30))
));
```

I have to define `hasSize()` myself:

```
public static <K, V> Matcher<Map<K, V>> hasSize(final int size) {
    return new TypeSafeMatcher<Map<K, V>>() {
        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(Map<K, V> kvMap) {
            return kvMap.size() == size;
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText(" has ").appendValue(size).appendText(" key/value pairs");
        }
    };
}
```

And there is another variant of `hasEntry()` that takes matchers as parameters instead of exact values of key and value. This can be useful in case you need something other than equality testing of every key and value.

Comment: Instead of using your own `hasSize` method, you should use, `org.hamcrest.collection.IsMapWithSize.aMapWithSize(Matcher<? super Integer>)`

Answer (score 4):

I favor using [Guava ImmutableMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html). They support `Map.equals()` and are easy to construct. The only trick is to explicitly specify type parameters, since hamcrest will assume the `ImmutableMap` type.

```
assertThat( actualValue,
            Matchers.<Map<String, String>>equalTo( ImmutableMap.of(
                "key1", "value",
                "key2", "other-value"
) ) );
```

Answer (score 4):

This works like a charm and doesn't require two assertions like the accepted answer.

```
assertThat( actualData.entrySet().toArray(), 
    arrayContainingInAnyOrder(expectedData.entrySet().toArray()) );
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option available now is to use the [Cirneco extension](https://github.com/ozimov/cirneco) for Hamcrest. It has [`hasSameKeySet()`](https://github.com/ozimov/cirneco/wiki/Hamcrest-extension-for-JDK7#same-keyset-matcher) (as well as other matchers for Guava "collections").
According to your example, it will be:

```
assertThat(affA, hasSameKeySet(affB));
```

You can use the following dependency for a JDK7-based project:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>it.ozimov</groupId>
  <artifactId>java7-hamcrest-matchers</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

or the following if you are using JDK8 or superior:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>it.ozimov</groupId>
  <artifactId>java8-hamcrest-matchers</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just compare the keys but not the values? The question wanted to compare values, too.

Comment: @Dr.Hans-PeterStörr No, the question shows that the entry sets are compared

Answer (score 0):

Hamcrest now has a `Matcher` for size collection.

`org.hamcrest.collection.IsCollectionWithSize`

Comment: That doesn't answer the original question.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to compare a set of results with expectations and if you choose to use [assertj](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/) library, you can do this:

```
// put set of expected values by your test keys
Map<K, V> expectations = ...;

// for each test key get result
Map<K, V> results = expectations.keySet().stream().collect(toMap(k -> k, k -> getYourProductionResult(k)));

assertThat(results).containsAllEntriesOf(expectations);
```

Note that `containsAllEntriesOf` does not compare maps for equality. If your production code returns actually a `Map<K, V>` you may want to add a check for keys `assertThat(results).containsOnlyKeys((K[]) expectations.keySet().toArray());`

Answer (score 0):

A quite simple way is to use a utility method from Guava's com.google.common.collect.Maps class.

```
assertThat(Maps.difference(map1,map2).areEqual(),is(true));
```

Comment: This however removes the descriptive assertion failures, which is one of the main reason of using Hamcrest.

Answer (score 0):

I came to this thread testing with groovy and org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.2

the method `isIn` is deprecated and the advice is to use `is(in(...))` instead.

However `in` is a keyword in groovy!

So I ended up aliasing the import to do:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.in as matchIn
....
....
@Test
void myTestMethod() {
    Map expectedSubMap = [
            one: "One",
            three: "Three"
            ]
    Map result = getMapToTest()
    assertThat(expectedSubMap.entrySet(), everyItem(is(matchIn(result.entrySet()))))
}
```